# Sagepay Error - 3045 : The Currency field is missing

Tags: php, opayo

Please do not mark it as duplicate. I have already gone through almost all the previous post for same issue, but was not able to tackle my error.
I am trying to upgrade the Sagepay Protocol from v2.23 to v3.00
I have also deployed PHP kit provided by Sagepay and getting the same error.
Below is the AES encryption I am using to make it compatible for v3.00 in my includes.php
Any guidance would be much appreciated.

```
<?


/* Base 64 Encoding function **
** PHP does it natively but just for consistency and ease of maintenance, let's declare our own function **/
function base64Encode($plain) {
  // Initialise output variable
  $output = "";

  // Do encoding
  $output = base64_encode($plain);

  // Return the result
  return $output;
}

/* Base 64 decoding function **
** PHP does it natively but just for consistency and ease of maintenance, let's declare our own function **/
function base64Decode($scrambled) {
  // Initialise output variable
  $output = "";

  // Fix plus to space conversion issue
  $scrambled = str_replace(" ","+",$scrambled);

  // Do encoding
  $output = base64_decode($scrambled);

  // Return the result
  return $output;
}


/*  The SimpleXor encryption algorithm                                                                                **
**  NOTE: This is a placeholder really.  Future releases of Form will use AES or TwoFish.  Proper encryption      **
**  This simple function and the Base64 will deter script kiddies and prevent the "View Source" type tampering        **
**  It won't stop a half decent hacker though, but the most they could do is change the amount field to something     **
**  else, so provided the vendor checks the reports and compares amounts, there is no harm done.  It's still          **
**  more secure than the other PSPs who don't both encrypting their forms at all                                      */

function simpleXor($InString, $Key) {
  // Initialise key array
  $KeyList = array();
  // Initialise out variable
  $output = "";

  // Convert $Key into array of ASCII values
  for($i = 0; $i < strlen($Key); $i++){
    $KeyList[$i] = ord(substr($Key, $i, 1));
  }

  // Step through string a character at a time
  for($i = 0; $i < strlen($InString); $i++) {
    // Get ASCII code from string, get ASCII code from key (loop through with MOD), XOR the two, get the character from the result
    // % is MOD (modulus), ^ is XOR
    $output.= chr(ord(substr($InString, $i, 1)) ^ ($KeyList[$i % strlen($Key)]));
  }

  // Return the result
  return $output;
}


//** Wrapper function do encrypt an encode based on strEncryptionType setting **
function encryptAndEncode($strPost) {

        global $strEncryptionType
              ,$strEncryptionPassword;

        if ($strEncryptionType=="XOR") 
        {
                //** XOR encryption with Base64 encoding **
                return base64Encode(simpleXor($strPost,$strEncryptionPassword));
        } 
        else 
        {
                //** AES encryption, CBC blocking with PKCS5 padding then HEX encoding - DEFAULT **

                //** use initialization vector (IV) set from $strEncryptionPassword
        $strIV = $strEncryptionPassword;

        //** add PKCS5 padding to the text to be encypted
        $strPost = addPKCS5Padding($strPost);

        //** perform encryption with PHP's MCRYPT module
                $strCrypt = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $strEncryptionPassword, $strPost, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $strIV);

                //** perform hex encoding and return
                return "@" . bin2hex($strCrypt);
        }
}


//** Wrapper function do decode then decrypt based on header of the encrypted field **
function decodeAndDecrypt($strPost) {

        global $strEncryptionPassword;

        if (substr($strPost,0,1)=="@") 
        {
                //** HEX decoding then AES decryption, CBC blocking with PKCS5 padding - DEFAULT **

                //** use initialization vector (IV) set from $strEncryptionPassword
        $strIV = $strEncryptionPassword;

        //** remove the first char which is @ to flag this is AES encrypted
        $strPost = substr($strPost,1); 

        //** HEX decoding
        $strPost = pack('H*', $strPost);

        //** perform decryption with PHP's MCRYPT module
                return mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $strEncryptionPassword, $strPost, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $strIV); 
        } 
        else 
        {
                //** Base 64 decoding plus XOR decryption **
                return simpleXor(base64Decode($strPost),$strEncryptionPassword);
        }
}


//** PHP's mcrypt does not have built in PKCS5 Padding, so we use this
function addPKCS5Padding($input)
{
   $blocksize = 16;
   $padding = "";

   // Pad input to an even block size boundary
   $padlength = $blocksize - (strlen($input) % $blocksize);
   for($i = 1; $i <= $padlength; $i++) {
      $padding .= chr($padlength);
   }

   return $input . $padding;
}

/*************
function pkcs5_pad($text, $blocksize)
    {
        $pad = $blocksize - (strlen($text) % $blocksize);
        //echo "<br/>Padding:".str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad)."<";
        return $text . str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad);
    }

    function encryptFieldData($input)
    {
        $key = "[mykey]";
        $iv = $key;

        $cipher = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, "", MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, "");
        if (mcrypt_generic_init($cipher, $key, $iv) != -1)
        {
            $cipherText = mcrypt_generic($cipher,$input );
            mcrypt_generic_deinit($cipher);

            $enc = bin2hex($cipherText);
        }
        return $enc;
    }
    $str = "Currency=GBP";
    $datapadded = pkcs5_pad($str,16);
    $cryptpadded = "@" . encryptFieldData($datapadded);
*************************/

?>
```

Comment: Hi @Moin what have you tried and what issues are you seeing? Its pretty difficult for people to help without this information or a valid test case.

Comment: Hi @Mark, I have changed only the parameters that's need to be changed. e.g. $strVendorName="[myvendorname]"; $strEncryptionPassword="[mypassword]"; etc.  I have created a confirm.php that captures the data from the form and passed it to Sagepay server in encrypt format; which gives me an error as "This transaction attempt has failed. We are unable to redirect you back to the web store from which you were purchasing. The details of the failure are given below.

Status:  MALFORMED

Status Detail:  3045 : The Currency field is missing."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with my server mcrypt PHP extension. It wasn't install/enable on the server. I must have consider this before making all test attempts.
Thank you all for the efforts towards my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your encryption password is correct? 3045 is the first error to be thrown if the password is wrong. This is not so nuts as it sounds - encryption passwords are different between test and live.....

Comment: Hi @Rik, yes I have triple checked my encryption password. I have properly used the test encryption password for the test URL.